# Executing Compiler flag through bash scripting

Tags: linux, bash, shell, arguments

I am new to bash scripting. I need to execute `dx` command that takes java class file and convert it into dex file. Here my java class file is `apple.class` and want output `classes.dex` file The command for conversion is:

```
dx -JXmx256m --debug --dex --dump-to=apple.lst --output=classes.dex --dump-width=1000 apple.class
```

I want to execute this command by bash script. Here are my approach:

**script.sh**

```
filelst="apple.lst"
filedex="classes.dex"
filecl="apple.class"

flag1="--dump-to=$file1st"
flag2="--output=$filedex"
flag3="--dump-width=1000 $filecl"
dx "--debug  --dex $flag1 $flag2 $flag3"
```

When I am running `bash script.sh` it send me error, showing steps for running dx command. But when I am running without bash script,it successfully execute. Please help me in writing correct way for this command in bash scripting.

```
error: no command specified                                                                                                                                
usage:                                                                                                                                                     
  dx --dex [--debug] [--verbose] ...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`dx` is seeing *one* argument, not separate arguments for `--debug`, `--dex`, etc. The usual approach is to leave `$flag1` et al unquoted:

```
dx --debug --dex $flag1 $flag2 $flag3
```

but that has problems of its own if any of the embedded options contain whitespace..

The correct solution is to use arrays to store multiple arguments.

```
filelst="apple.lst"
filedex="classes.dex"
filecl="apple.class"

flag1="--dump-to=$filelst"
flag2="--output=$filedex"
flag3=( --dump-width=1000 "$filecl")
dx --debug  --dex "$flag1" "$flag2" "${flag[@]}"
```

or more simply

```
flags=(--dump-to="$filelst" --output="$filedex" --dump-width=1000 "$filecl")
dx --debug --dex "{$flags[@]}"
```